# Java Swing BorderLayout make one region not resizable

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout

I have a Java Swing GUI where the top level layout manager is BorderLayout.  I'd like it so that when the user resizes my GUI below the preferred size the center region can't be resized any smaller (or at least takes precedence in resizing) and the north/south regions become smaller.

The way it's working right now is my north and south panels are taking precedence and blowing away my center region first.  I've tried setting a minimum size on the center panel once it has all of its components added to it

```
centerPanel.setMinimumSize(centerPanel.getPreferredSize());
```

but that isn't working for me.  It's still the first region to minimize on a resize.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have a feeling I need to at least change the layout manager I'm using.  I'd rather not since I like the way everything looks right now and other than this problem, it's working perfectly.  I guess I'll find out shortly!

Comment: Consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) so we can have code to play around with, to better *experience* your problem, and hopefully then help find a simple solution.

Comment: @trashgod: I'll delete my comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a BoxLayout will work. Box layout will respect the minimum size of a component. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Box Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything simpler than GridBagLayout will serve.  BorderLayout is not good about honoring minimum sizes.